# Motor running slow using PWM

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pwm, dc-motor

I'm new to PWM. This is my [motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N9LMQ43) and [controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014KMHSW6). When I have the jumper in (ENA pins: I assume this gives the PWM pin the full 5V, as that is what the controller board runs on). My 6V 47 RPM motor goes at full speed. When I use PWM from my Pi, the speed reduces significantly, even on 100% duty.

Could this be because my GPIO PWM pin only allows 3V out from the Pi 3? Or am I possibly not understanding PWM? I am running a for loop to run at 100% duty cycle and increase the frequency gradually from 0 to 100Hz.

Also, before anyone asks, it is a 6V motor on a controller board that takes 5V. It doesn't need an external PSU unless you run a motor over 12V.

Comment: the links to the motor and the controller give an error "site can not be reached" for me.  Looks like a problem with the URL. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187226/how-does-voltage-and-current-affect-speed-and-torque-of-a-motor as well as https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/tech-blog/2015/08/03/dc-motor-speed-voltage-and-torque-relationships both of which indicate motor speed is directly proportional to voltage so long as the voltage is in the operating range of the motor and the load on the motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood how PWM is used to control DC motor speed.

To control the speed you vary the duty cycle, not the frequency.  The frequency should be fixed at a reasonable value for your motor driver board.  Say anything over 100 Hz.

A duty cycle of 0% stops the motor.  A duty cycle of 100% sets the motor full on.

The voltage applied to the motor will be roughly supply voltage multiplied by duty cycle percentage divided by 100.

The motor will start spinning at some value of duty cycle above 0%.  From that value to 100% duty cycle the speed increase will be fairly linear.

An [example using PWM](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=90243) with a L298N based driver board.

Comment: Thank you, so I tried setting duty to 100 and tried a freq to 100,1000,10000 and didn't see any change. I'd there a frequency "sweet spot"?

Comment: Not really for the L298N (as you have).  I'd use 800 Hz simply because it is a fairly default value.  The L298N does drop about 1.5 volts from the supply voltage (from memory).

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you're not using an external power supply for the motor?

This motor probably requires a separate supply. I could not find the stall current for the motor, but under load the motor will probably drop the power enough that the Raspberry Pi no longer functions.

However, that isn't the worst problem. Motors are very noisy, electrically speaking. This means that they put voltage spikes into power wires. And when you stop a motor, while it's stopping, the motor turns into a generator and will put power back into the system. You will need capacitors to deal with the voltage spikes and a clamping diode to deal with the reverse current flow.

You *can* put motors on the same power supply as the electronics, but you have to be very careful.

I am very careful about my power supplies when I build robots. I usually use two different batteries, but that's my choice. Sometimes I will use a single power supply, and then I will take precautions.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to use [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to control the motor. It simplifies the [PWM](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#pwmoutputdevice) control down to a 0 to 1 value scale, and the [Motor](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#motor) class provides `forward()`, `backward()`, `stop()` and value setting from -1 to 1.